# How to select variables (not text) with the same name?

Tags: sublimetext2

When selecting variable `f`, the editor highlights other occurrences of the variable. So far so good, but when trying to add them to the selection list with `Ctrl+D`, it also adds `f` as it occurs in the code as regular text. I can skip this with `Ctrl+K`, but if the editor already identifies `f` as a variable, then it can surely also just select variables? This option is not in the menu.

Take this JavaScript snippet.

```
f=function(){};
f();
```

When selecting the first `f`, it also highlights `f` in `f()`, but not `f` in `function`.
When multi-selecting with `Ctrl+D` it does select it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It's a bug.](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8573) The post also has the workaround.

Rather than selecting the variable, just put the cursor left to it, and press `Ctrl+D`. This will also select it, but only other variables (or what the editor recognises as variables, based on word boundaries) on subsequent `Ctrl+D` presses.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `word_separators` option to not include your variable prefix (i.e. `$` for PHP) so when you double-click a variable name, it will select `$` as well.

This option is located in the file `Preferences.sublime-settings` in your `Default` folder. I recommend adding the modified setting to `Preferences.sublime-settings` in your `User` folder rather than changing the defaults.

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
```

**Edit**:

Unfortunately, currently there's no way to do a Find & Replace within a certain scope. The issue has been raised [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7066), and you can vote for it as a feature request on [Sublime's UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/117733-edit-all-occurrences-of-string-in-scope/).

Comment: This is in JavaScript, so the variable is just named `f`. The editor does know that it's a variable though. I'll add a code snippet to explain it better.

Comment: In that case, it's unfortunately not possible without a plugin, and none seem to exist yet for this purpose. There is an open feature request on their forum though (see my edit), so I'd suggest upvoting it there.

Comment: Hmmm, so it doesn't really know about the variable (as it doesn't parse the code), but why does it only **highlight** the appropriate `f`s, yet also **selects** the `f` in `function` when using `Ctrl+D`? If you try the code snippet with JavaScript Syntax, you'll notice immediately. If this isn't implemented yet, it should be really easy to do so.

Comment: I see what you mean; I'm sure it's possible with a plugin, but I do wonder why the good folks at the ST2 forum haven't come up with one yet. In the meantime, a small-scale workaround might be regex Find & Replace, i.e. `\bf\b` > `g`

Comment: The [RegReplace](https://github.com/facelessuser/RegReplace/) plugin may actually do what you want with the `scope_filter` option.

Comment: It's a bug. I've answered my own question if you don't mind. Thanks for the suggestions.