# Sublime Text 2 ctrl+d doesn't always select the next matching string

Tags: sublimetext2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select variables (not text) with the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184437/how-to-select-variables-not-text-with-the-same-name)

```
$project_id = $this->user_model->get_project_id();
$project_id = 'yo';
```

If I double click the first instance of `project_id`, it'll highlight it, then pressing ctrl+d will select `project_id` inside of `get_project_id` ctrl+d again will select `project_id` on line 2.

Or if I put my cursor on the first `project_id`, then hit ctrl+d, it'll select it for me. BUT, the second time I hit ctrl+d, it'll skip `get_project_id` and go to line 2.

I hope someone could follow that. Is this a bug, or a feature? Why would I want it to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug.

If you select a string, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will search for every occurrence of that string, even if it is a partial of another string.

If you put your cursor on a string, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will look for the exact occurrences of that string.

I find this useful, even if it was a bug. :)

Comment: I see, that's a bit confusing. I didn't know there were different ways in which something could be selected.

Comment: rocks! and remember press left button of the mouse and hold it when type CTRL+D

Answer (score 1):

[This behavior is a bug](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8573). You can report it at Sublime Text's [UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/).